# Why does Java scrollPane remove contents of my Panel when I scroll Up and Down?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, scrollbar, scrollpane

I have a problem with the *scrollPane* in Java.

I am programming a GUI using *Java*, where I have implemented a Panel using JPanel with a scroll bar.

To simplify my idea for better understanding, the Panel displays a number of Jlabels depending on the number entered by the user.

So the width and height of the Panel will be dynamically changed each time the user enters a different value.

```
JPanel inP=new JPanel(); 
inP.setLayout(null);
inP.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1000, 1000));

scroll=new JScrollPane(inP,JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS,JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
scroll.setBounds(10, 20, 830, 440);
lowP.add(scroll);
```

As you can see, I created the Jpanel with Preferred size as constants (for simplicity, although it will be dynamic).

However, the probelm is that when I run the code, the vertical scrollbar appears, but when I scroll down, the rest of the Jlabel do not appears (Its like a cut in the graph).

What's weird is that when I scroll back up, the graph returns to its initial state and ignore the update I just applied.

What's also strange is that the horizontal scroll bar works fine and shows whats left of the graph from the right side.

Here are some photos to show my problem:

Here is an image for how it looks when I scroll down:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lxR0F.png]

Comment: You've got a bug in your program, likely in code not shown, and you'll want to create and post a valid [mcve], a minimal program, small enough to be posted in your question as code-formatted text, one that compiles and runs, and that demonstrates your problem for us. It's not your whole program, it doesn't have all it's functionality, but again it runs for us, and it demonstrates the problem for us.

Comment: Note that we're not requesting your entire program, but rather a small new program that demonstrates your problem. Side note: I have to ask if you're overriding a painting method anywhere or using null layouts, both of which can mess up JScrollPane functioning.

Comment: `inP.setLayout(null);` -- ah, you are. This is a **very bad thing** and something that JScrollPanes don't handle well, and also is coding against the GUI library rather than with it. Learn and use the layout managers.

Answer (score 2):

> but when I scroll down, the rest of the Jlabel do not appears (Its like a cut in the graph).

It is the job of the layout manager to determine the preferred size of the components added to the panel. Scrolling only works if this value is calculated correctly. Don't use a null layout. Let the layout manager do its job.

> So the width and height of the Panel will be dynamically changed each time the user enters a different value.

Don't use `setPreferredSize(...)`!!!

The layout manager will dynmacally determine the preferred size as you add components. Your basic code should just be:

```
panel.add(...);
panel.revalidate();
panel.repaint();
```